# viewing events in winforms

Tags: winforms

How can I choose which event is shown when I double click on a control in winforms designer?

For example, winforms shows the "TextChanged" event when I double click on a textbox. If I wanted to make it show the "GotFocus" event, how could I do that? I am guessing I would inherit textbox and set some property, but I cant find that property.

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to override the default `.NET` controls event patten without completely rewriting the way that the control is raising the events. What makes you think that you just set a property to change the event structure.

Comment: Because each default control in VS calls a different event. And i'm lazy. Anyways, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the [DefaultEvent] attribute by inheriting from the control:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DefaultEvent("GotFocus")]
class MyTextBox : TextBox { 
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote you twice, this really helped me today.

Answer (score 1):

The deafult event is defined with [`DefaultEventAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaulteventattribute%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class. So unless you have access to the control code, you cant change existing ones.

By inheriting you can by using that attribute.